# Web push Notification doen't work on my Vue application

Tags: javascript, vue.js, push-notification, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

i'am working on a web push notification using firestore and vuejs. What i'am trying to do is to send notification to my app when a value of my table is changed. I have deploy a cloud function and set up a service worker.
here's my code

```
> const functions = require('firebase-functions');
> 
> const admin = require('firebase-admin'); admin.initializeApp();
> 
> exports.notifyNewMessage = functions.firestore  
> .document('plc_value/{id_value}')   .onUpdate((change, context) => {
>     const newValue = change.after.data();
>     const previousValue = change.before.data();
>     const name = newValue.name;
> 
>         return admin.firestore().doc('users/' + recipientId).get().then(userDoc => {
>             const registrationTokens = userDoc.get('registrationTokens')
> 
>             const notificationBody = (message['type'] === "TEXT") ? message['text'] : "You received a new image message."
>             const payload = {
>                 notification: {
>                     title: senderName + " sent you a message.",
>                     body: notificationBody,
>                     icon: 'https://content.cdn.intranetdashboard.com/images/icon-push-notifications.png'
>                 }
>             }
> 
>             return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(registrationTokens, payload).then( response => {
>                 const stillRegisteredTokens = registrationTokens
> 
>                 response.results.forEach((result, index) => {
>                     const error = result.error
>                     if (error) {
>                         const failedRegistrationToken = registrationTokens[index]
>                         console.error('blah', failedRegistrationToken, error)
>                         if (error.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token'
>                             || error.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered') {
>                                 const failedIndex = stillRegisteredTokens.indexOf(failedRegistrationToken)
>                                 if (failedIndex > -1) {
>                                     stillRegisteredTokens.splice(failedIndex, 1)
>                                 }
>                             }
>                     }
>                 })
> 
>                 return admin.firestore().doc("users/" + recipientId).update({
>                     registrationTokens: stillRegisteredTokens
>                 })
>             })
>         })
>     })
```